# ASP.NET, Code on click of a next button

Tags: asp.net

The following is my code, I am doing project on online examination in that I have a module of question to display in this when I click on next button it should go to the next question but it is not going.

```
    public partial class Student : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);

        int i=1; 
        Session["Number"] = i;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         Session["Number"] = i++;
         Label1.Text = Session["Number"].ToString();

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Questions where QuestionNo = '"+Label1.Text+"'", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                Label2.Text = dr["Question"].ToString();
                Label3.Text = dr["Ans1"].ToString();
                Label4.Text = dr["Ans2"].ToString();
                Label5.Text = dr["Ans3"].ToString();
                Label6.Text = dr["Ans4"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from Answers where QuestionNo = '" + Label1.Text + "'", con);
            SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr1.Read())
            {
                Label8.Text = dr1["Answer"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();   
    }
    protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            Label7.Text = Label3.Text;
        }
    }
    protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton2.Checked)
        {
            Label7.Text = Label4.Text;
        }
    }
    protected void RadioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton3.Checked)
        {
            Label7.Text = Label5.Text;
        }
    }
    protected void RadioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton4.Checked)
        {
            Label7.Text = Label6.Text;
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Label7.Text == Label8.Text)
        {
            Label9.Text = "Your Answer is correct";
        }
        else
            Label9.Text = "Your Answer is incorrect";
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        Session["Number"] = i;
        Response.Redirect("Student.aspx");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So many bad things in this code.

1. You should always give names to your variables properly.
2. Don't concatenate SQL queries because security reasons like SQL Injection
3. You should use `Session["Number"]` to select the question number rather than Label1.Text.
4. Use session when it was only necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you are doing wrong is how you are trying to store value of `i` in your Session. You are overwriting it every time you get into the method and thus resulting in same question number on each button click.

Second, you should parametrized your queries.

On each button click you should retrieve the value of `i` from your session and then increment it and again store it in the session. like:

```
int i = 0;
if (Session["Number"] == null)
{
    Session["Number"] = i;
}
else
{
    i = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Number"]);
}
//Later To increment Session

Session["Number"] = ++i; //First increments, then assigns the value
```

You should also use `++i` instead of `i++` since that will store the value of `i` before increment.

Comment: @losSebos, thanks for the edit, yes it should have been `==` , not `!=`.

Comment: This code worked...thank you.. there is one more problem...if i click on next button it goes to next question that is fine..but i have only 5 questions in my database...but when i click the next button after the 5th question the question no. changes to 6 and it goes on changing but question remains the same... how to stop this thing...if i have 5 questions then it should not go beyond that...help me..